# c# Moq a method with an optional parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I can't set up a mock for a method with optional parameters. Say I have a class and interface like  :

```
public class Bird : iBird
{
    public void Chirp(string name = "BigBird")
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

public interface iBird
{
    void Chirp(string name = "Tweetie");
}
```

If I setup the Chirp method mock with a parameter :

```
[TestClass]
public class BirdTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void chirpTest()
    {
        var c = new Mock<Bird>();
        c.Setup(x => x.Chirp(It.IsAny<string>()));
        c.Object.Chirp("Woody");
    }
}
```

When I run the test I get :

> Test method BirdTests.chirpTest threw exception: 
>   System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual
>   (overridable in VB) member: x => x.Chirp(It.IsAny())

If I take the It.IsAny() out it won't compile.

How can I mock this method?

Comment: Judging by the error message, it seems that the method not being `virtual` is the problem, not the optional parameter

Comment: You're right, and I'm blind. So how do I give you points if you don't add an answer?

Comment: I can add an answer with a bit more detail

Comment: If you mock `iBird` instead it should work just fine. Note that when mocking concrete objects you should also consider whether the base class method should be called.

Comment: Kaleb, you're right. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually that the method is not marked `virtual`, not that the method has an optional parameter:

> Test method BirdTests.chirpTest threw exception: System.NotSupportedException: **Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member**: x => x.Chirp(It.IsAny())

In order to mock a method with Moq, that method must be marked `virtual` so that the proxy class that Moq generates can provide it's own implementation of the method you're mocking.